# console log in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, console.log

I have a problem that I don't see my console log at all and I want to know if a mange to enter the cookie in my controller that I have in my html page.

```
var addPartyApp = angular.module('addPartyApp',['ngCookies']);   


addPartyApp.controller('partyController',['$scope','$http', '$cookies', function($scope,$http,$cookies){


console.log("works!");

    //  $scope.createParty = function(){     
               var data = {};      
                data.title = $scope.title;
                data.description = $scope.description;
                data.image = $scope.myFile;
                data.email = $scope.cookie;
                console.log($scope.cookie);
                console.log($scope.myFile);
                console.log(data); 
            $http.post('http://localhost:3000/party', data).then() //callback 
      //}

}]);
```

I really want to know what the problem is because I use console log a lot and without it it's really hard for my to check myself

thanks!

the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="addPartyApp">
 <head>
   <title>show party</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
 </head>
 <body ng-controller="partyController">
  <h1 class="text-center">Add Party</h1>
        <form class="form-group" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="http://localhost:3000/party">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title:</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="title" name="title" required></input>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description:</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" type="text" placeholder="Description" ng-model="description" name="description" required></textarea>
              <br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <br>
              <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" required></input>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <br>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="send"></input>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
    <script src="js/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="js/addParty.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this

```
addPartyApp.controller('partyController',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http,$cookies){
```

You don't seem to be injecting $cookies there.

Try this:

```
addPartyApp.controller('partyController',['$scope','$http', '$cookies', function($scope,$http,$cookies){
```

This is not related to console.log at all. It is rather a problem with the fact that you are not executing the lines of code where your console.logs are found

Comment: forgot to add it after a tried to delete it because it didn't work and I though the cookies are the problem - still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

```js
var addPartyApp = angular.module('addPartyApp', []);


addPartyApp.controller('partyController', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {


    console.log("works!");

    //  $scope.createParty = function(){     
    var data = {};
    data.title = $scope.title;
    data.description = $scope.description;
    data.image = $scope.myFile;
    data.email = $scope.cookie;
    console.log($scope.cookie);
    console.log($scope.myFile);
    console.log(data);
    $http.post('http://localhost:3000/party', data).then() //callback 
      //}

  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="addPartyApp">

<head>
  <title>show party</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="partyController">
  <h1 class="text-center">Add Party</h1>
  <form class="form-group" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="http://localhost:3000/party">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="title" name="title" required />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" type="text" placeholder="Description" ng-model="description" name="description" required></textarea>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <br>
        <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" required />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="send" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Have a look at angular's dependency injection  inline Array Annotation documentation:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

> take care to keep the annotation array in sync with the parameters in the function declaration.

Add `'$cookies'`

```
addPartyApp.controller('partyController',['$scope','$http', '$cookies',function($scope,$http,$cookies){
```

Comment: where are you calling `createParty ` function?, can you add the html code?

Comment: you dont seem to be calling the `createParty `  anywhere in the code, try placing the `console.log` outside the function and i think you'll see it works just fine, or add some `ng-click="createParty()"` somewhere and click it

Comment: @WalksAway is right you seem to not be calling $scope.createParty anywhere. That should be your fix

Comment: still nothing from the console log

Comment: you still aren't calling the function... try putting the `console.log()` outside the `createParty` inside the controller function, it works just fine

Comment: any way, what you want to do here (from what i see) is to use `ng-submit="createParty()"` on your form  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit , this will call the createParty function whenever the form is submitted

Comment: I saved the from details in mLab but I what to add the cookie so I would know which user has entered the information.
and after that I need to create a wish list so I have to know which user is signed in...

Comment: one more thing inputs should be using like this: `<input type="text".../>` not `<input></input>` In HTML, the <input> tag has no end tag.

Comment: fix the input tags... In HTML, the <input> tag has no end tag. close it with `<input/>`

Comment: everything is ok now?